# Image Search in the Search bar of the Dspace6.0

Tags: dspace

In dspace6.0 , there is a search button at the top which is used to search the Community,Collections and Items.

In that Item of collection , I  uploaded  somefilename.pdf . Now if I type the somefilename.pdf in the Search button, corresponding  item is getting returned, Similarly if type the contents of the somefilename.pdf in the search box , still I am able to get the item .

In the same way , If I upload any IMAGE  like someimage.jpeg  in the Item , I am not able to find that image .

I just wanted to know can we search the uploaded image name  of Item in the Search bar or not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the search repository in your Solr admin console, you will see that the name of the PDF file is added to the search index when full text extraction is performed on the PDF.

Since images are not processed by the the full text indexer, the name is not captured in the search index.